# How to remove thread safe error in aspnet core middleware invoke method?

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

Getting exception "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."
Below is the code.

```
  public  Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var userId =context.Session.GetString("UserId");
                if (userId != null)
                {
                    var user =_context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
                    user.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                { }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            return this._next(context);
        }
```

Comment: This won't be much help, but I'm encountering the same issue.  I've been trying all sorts of things to correct this and having little success.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code but I'm guessing:

1. _context is your db context
2. you're injecting it via the ctor

As you've discovered, this probably won't work.

Instead, inject your db context via the Invoke method.

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context, YourDbContext dbContext)
{
  try 
  { 
      var userId = context.Session.GetString("UserId"); 
      if (userId != null) 
      { 
          var user = dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault(); 
          ...
      }
   }
   catch(Exception ex){...}
}
```

This ensures you have a scoped instance of your db context, which should be threadsafe.